# Connection string is not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
DB="Source={SQL Server};Server=CALVINRUKA-PC\SQLCALVIN;DataSource=DWDSCal\Tables;Uid=sa;PWD=;Trusted-Connection=Yes;"
```

I using SQL Server 2008 R2 to connect with HTML page. I trying to connect HTML page with login to SQL Database. I have try called the Source but didnt work.

Comment: Not working how?  What error(s) are you seeing?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you trying to connect to? Also, what does a connection string have to do with HTML?

Comment: I using SQL Server to make string connection so my HTML page have some function. I have call the source from SQL Server but didnt give any respone. I ensure the problem is came from here. What is doing is just a login page.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, I using SQL Server 2008 R2. This connection string is to make my HTML login page with SQL Database.

Comment: What's your HTML page extension? .HTML?

Comment: Rubens Farias, index.htm to consultation.htm. Before move to concultation.htm, at index.htm will required login username and password.

Answer (score 1):

As you've said you're using SQL Server 2008 R2, try using a connection string in this format:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Also ensure that you've enabled `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode` in your SQL Server settings.

Comment: Pal, this what is put in my code. Still not working. I also ensure i nable SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode too.

Data Source=CALVINRUKA-PC\SQLCALVIN;Initial Catalog=DWDSCal;User Id=Lid;Password=LPassword;

Answer (score 0):

To create a valid connection string, you can:

- Create an empty text file, named `connection.udl`
- Double-click it
- Enter your server name
- Select "Allow saving password" and fill other data
- Select your database
- Click "Test connection" button
- If everything is ok, click ok and confirm saving password
- Open this file in Notepad

For ASP.NET, you will use everything *except* `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;`

Comment: My previous question have my all code in there. Hope u can help me. Thank You